# Roundup Index Match with Multiple Criteria to Next 3 Values in Excel Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with box dimensions in it and associated costs for the box. Sometimes, I am given box dimensions that do not fit in the box table, so I need to either round them up so I make sure the product can still fit in the box and the cost value is correct.

In another sheet, I have a formula where I am using an Index Match with multiple criteria, but I need the Index Match to be more dynamic and match to the nearest available value by rounding up in my **Box Packaging Cost Formula**:

```
=INDEX('Packaging cost data'!$F$18:$F$77,MATCH(1,([@Length3]='Packaging cost data'!$B$18:$B$77)*([@Width2]='Packaging cost data'!$C$18:$C$77)*([@Height2]='Packaging cost data'!$D$18:$D$77),0))
```

In the above formula:

- I have already tried changing my 0 at the end of the formula to not be exact, either -1 or 1, and that did not work properly
- My inputs examples are shown here:

  [image: Inputs]
- The input of 5, 5, 5 should be rounded up to 8,6,4 given 5, 5, 5 arent values for Length, Width, and Height. The correct result of the Index Match should be a Box Packaging Cost of .48.
- The input 12, 5, 4 should be rounded up to 12,6,4 given 12 is a valid length and 6 is a valid height, but 5 is not a valid height. The correct result of the Index Match should then be a Box Packaging Cost of .62
- Packaging cost data is the table shown below
- F18 to F77 for Packaging Cost Data Is the same as A2 to A61 if you were to apply this table to a new sheet with headers

## Packaging Cost Data

[image: Packging Cost Data]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dimensions `5,5,5` should be rounded to `8,6,6` not `8,6,4`, following formula works:

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$18,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/((A2<=$F$2:$F$18)*(B2<=$G$2:$G$18)*(C2<=$H$2:$H$18)))*ROW($I$2:$I$18)-1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: you can shorten that formula up a little by using full column reference for the index portion (eliminates the -1).  Instead of dividing 1 by your search criteria  then multiply by the row() just skip the 1 and directly divide the row().  `INDEX($I:$I,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($I$2:$I$18)/((A2<=$F$2:$F$18)*(B2<=$G$2:$G$18)*(C2<=$H$2:$H$18)),1))`

Comment: Both the original answer and @ForwardEd's answer worked perfectly. Thank you so much!